# Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: hadoop

I try run hadoop:

`hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar pi 4 100`
and get error:

> java.net.ConnectionException: ... to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception... Connection refused.

When I run:
`telnet localhost`
then I get:

> Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused